# Gmail possibly hacked?

Tags: gmail

I just noticed that my Gmail address has a different name attached to it.  I was taking a pic with my iPhone (to place an ad) and forwarded it to myself through email in order to use a different device to post.  When I type in my address - the name "Holidays in United States" was there instead of my name.

Recently I had a friend tell me they got an odd email from me.  Turns out it wasn't real - but it was the only one I'm aware of.  I'm assuming now that my email was hacked.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably the “Send mail as:” setting that is the problem. To change it:

1. Click the [image] gear in the top right.
2. Select **Settings**.
3. Click the **Accounts*8 tab.
4. In the “Send mail as:” section, locate the email address you'd like to edit.
5. Click **edit info** next to the address.
6. In the “Name:” section, specify what you’d like your name to be and click **Save changes**.

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158).